# ambiguos line in real world example of rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

can anybody explain this line of code ?

```
@current_user ||= super || User.find(@current_user_id)
```

I couldn't get what's the logic here, this is taken from [link to github](https://github.com/gothinkster/rails-realworld-example-app/blob/a2ae4fff78b3337683cea988c023281dcb5551b9/app/controllers/application_controller.rb#L37)

Comment: It looks broken. If you actually make it to `User.find(@current_user_id)` you're calling `User.find(nil)`.

Comment: maybe we're missing something from the context ?

Comment: `@current_user = @current_user || super || User.find(@current_user_id)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `||=` operator assigns the result of the right side expression to `@current_user` if the value of `@current_user` is `nil`, `false`, or undefined. If `@current_user` has a truthy value, it doesn't evaluate the right side of the expression and life continues as normal.

In this case, if `@current_user` is falsy, it first tries calling the same method on the parent class via `super`. If that returns `nil` or `false`, it calls `User.find(@current_user_id)`. The code appears to be assuming that `@current_user_id` is set whether or not `@current_user` is loaded. If `@current_user_id` *isn't* set, it will raise an `ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound` error at that point.